# smarty: in_array x, y

Tags: smarty

Can someone help me with smarty syntax for "in_array"?
I want to check if 2 variables in array:

```
{if in_array(($x,$y), $array)}var x and var y are in this array{/if}
```

is this syntax and or semantic right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an issue of "smarty syntax", but rather an issue of using the PHP function `in_array` correctly. Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```
{if in_array($x, $array) && in_array($y, $array)}var x and var y are in this array{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call in_array for each variable to check:

```
{if in_array($x, $array) && in_array($y, $array)}var x and var y are in this array{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to check that both `$x` and `$y` are in `$array`, so you need two conditions in your `{if}`

```
{if in_array($x, $array) && in_array($y, $array)}var x and var y are in this array{/if}
```